# How does Scala Slick translate Scala code into JDBC?

Tags: scala, slick

How does [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) translate code such as:

```
val q2 = for {
  c <- Coffees if c.price < 9.0
  s <- Suppliers if s.id === c.supID
} yield (c.name, s.name)
for(t <- q2) println("  " + t._1 + " supplied by " + t._2)
```

Into JDBC?

Does it use Scala Virtualized? Does it use some other method?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Slick's *stable API* achieves this via what it calls *lifted embedding*.  Your example is clearly using the stable API (as you use `===` for equality and not `==`).

The beauty of Slick (and in turn Scala) is that - this much is achieved without using macros or Scala-Virtualized.  *(Side Note: Slick's **experimental API** does use macros - and this will allow you to use `==` instead of `===` or `is`)*

The translation to SQL is achieved using:

1. Scala's `for` comprehension syntax, which is translated to method calls. 
   Tables defined in Slick are ***Monads*** - they have the magic `foreach`, `map`, 
   `flatMap`, and
   `filter` methods which allow them to be expressed in `for` 'loops' while Scala
   translates them to method calls (as correctly illustrated in the code 
   provided by [the other answer by @emil-ivanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758657/1305344)).

   As with regular Scala collections, the `for` is syntactic sugar for nested
   method calls to `flatMap`/`map` and `filter`; *unlike* regular collections,
   the Slick `Table` objects' versions of `map` and `filter` return *representations*
   of a query, building it along with every filter condition (`if`) or join
   (as in `s <- Suppliers if s.id is c.supID`)

   So the *type* of `q2` is not your usual collection (as a for comprehension in Scala
   is typically used to return), but rather a representation of a query. 
   (Just as the [Scala Option Monad](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) also works with `for` comprehensions despite
   not being a 'collection' (in the way that `List` or `Map` is))

   You can see the underlying query with `q2.selectStatement`.
2. Scala's implicit *lifting* - `c.price` is not an `Int` but rather a representation of 
   a column value - so the expression `c.price < 9.0` becomes `c.price.<(Const(9.0))` 
   (an `Int` is lifted to the desired type), and `<` is a just a method of the
   class that represents `c.price`, a `Column`. The `<` method
   does not do what `<` usually does (in the case of plain `Int`s) - it simply returns
   a representation of the SQL AST corresponding to `price < 9` that becomes part of
   the SQL that is generated and sent off to JDBC to execute.

There's a whole lot else going on, in terms of details, but I think the query monad and the implicit lifting are the chief ingredients.

Comment: Really great post. The implicit lifting is quite smart

Answer (score 15):

In Scala the `for` "loop" isn't actually a special language construct, but rather syntactic sugar. Your first example

```
val q2 = for {
  c <- Coffees if c.price < 9.0
  s <- Suppliers if s.id === c.supID
} yield (c.name, s.name)
```

translates to something in the lines of:

```
val q2 = Coffees.withFilter(_.price < 9.0).flatMap(c =>
    Suppliers.withFilter(_.id === c.supID).map(s =>
        (c.name, s.name)
    )
)
```

Now, the `flatMap`, `map`, `withFilter` (and `foreach`) do not actually filter the collection, but rather collect what's hapening in an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), which is then handled to Slick to translate to SQL.

Also, `c.price`, `c.supID` are actually Slick `column`s, whose `<`, `>`, `===` (and so on) methods don't return bool, but collect the comparison as well, which 
is later passed down to be converted to SQL.

[This is a talk](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/slick-database-access-with-scala/ac-5896) by the creators, where most of this is described (correctly).