# scala slick method I can not understand so far

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, magic-methods, scalaquery, slick

I try to understand some Slick works and what it requires.

Here it an example:

```
package models

case class Bar(id: Option[Int] = None, name: String)

object Bars extends Table[Bar]("bar") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  // This is the primary key column
  def name = column[String]("name")

  // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
  def * = id.? ~ name <>(Bar, Bar.unapply _)
}
```

Could somebody explain me what's the purpose of `*` method here, what is `<>`, why `unapply`? and what is Projection - method `~`' returns the instance of `Projection2`?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** - *added (yet another) explanation on `for` comprehensions*

1. The `*` method:

   This returns the *default projection* - which is how you describe:

   > 'all the columns (or computed values) I am *usually* interested' in.

   Your table could have several fields; you only need a subset for
   your default projection. The default projection must match the type
   parameters of the table.

   Let's take it one at a time. Without the `<>` stuff, just the `*`:

   ```
   // First take: Only the Table Defintion, no case class:

   object Bars extends Table[(Int, String)]("bar") {
     def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
     def name = column[String]("name")

     def * = id ~ name // Note: Just a simple projection, not using .? etc
   }

   // Note that the case class 'Bar' is not to be found. This is 
   // an example without it (with only the table definition)
   ```

   Just a table definition like that will let you make queries like:

   ```
   implicit val session: Session = // ... a db session obtained from somewhere

   // A simple select-all:
   val result = Query(Bars).list   // result is a List[(Int, String)]
   ```

   the default projection of `(Int, String)` leads to a `List[(Int, String)]` 
   for simple queries such as these.

   ```
   // SELECT b.name, 1 FROM bars b WHERE b.id = 42;
   val q = 
      for (b <- Bars if b.id === 42) 
        yield (b.name ~ 1)
        // yield (b.name, 1) // this is also allowed: 
                             // tuples are lifted to the equivalent projection.
   ```

   What's the type of `q`? It is a `Query` with the projection `(String, Int)`.
    When invoked, it returns a `List` of `(String, Int)` tuples as per the projection.

   ```
    val result: List[(String, Int)] = q.list
   ```

   In this case, you have defined the projection you want in the `yield` clause
    of the `for` comprehension.
2. Now about `<>` and `Bar.unapply`.

   This provides what are called *Mapped Projections*.

   So far we've seen how slick allows you to express queries in Scala
   that return a *projection of columns* (or computed values); So when executing
   these queries *you have to think of the result row* of a query **as a Scala tuple**.
   The type of the tuple will match the Projection that is defined (by your 
   `for` comprehension as in the previous example, of by the default `*` projection).
   This is why `field1 ~ field2` returns a projection of `Projection2[A, B]` where
   `A` is the type of `field1` and `B` is the type of `field2`.

   ```
   q.list.map {
     case (name, n) =>  // do something with name:String and n:Int
   }

   Queury(Bars).list.map {
     case (id, name) =>  // do something with id:Int and name:String 
   }
   ```

   We're dealing with tuples, which may be cumbersome if we have too many 
   columns. We'd like to think of results not as `TupleN` but rather some
   object with named fields.

   ```
   (id ~ name)  // A projection

   // Assuming you have a Bar case class:
   case class Bar(id: Int, name: String) // For now, using a plain Int instead
                                         // of Option[Int] - for simplicity

   (id ~ name <> (Bar, Bar.unapply _)) // A MAPPED projection

   // Which lets you do:
   Query(Bars).list.map ( b.name ) 
   // instead of
   // Query(Bars).list.map { case (_, name) => name }

   // Note that I use list.map instead of mapResult just for explanation's sake.
   ```

   How does this work? `<>` takes a projection `Projection2[Int, String]` and
   returns a mapped projection on the type `Bar`. The two arguments `Bar, Bar.unapply _`
   tell slick how this `(Int, String)` projection must be mapped to a case class.

   This is a two-way mapping; `Bar` is the case class constructor, so that's the
   information needed to go from `(id: Int, name: String)` to a `Bar`. And `unapply`
   if you've guessed it, is for the reverse.

   Where does `unapply` come from?  This is a standard Scala method available for
   any ordinary case class - just defining `Bar` gives you a `Bar.unapply` which 
   is an **extractor** that can be used to get back the `id` and `name` that the
   `Bar` was built with:

   ```
   val bar1 = Bar(1, "one")
   // later
   val Bar(id, name) = bar1  // id will be an Int bound to 1,
                             // name a String bound to "one"
   // Or in pattern matching
   val bars: List[Bar] = // gotten from somewhere
   val barNames = bars.map {
     case Bar(_, name) => name
   }

   val x = Bar.unapply(bar1)  // x is an Option[(String, Int)]
   ```

   So your default projection can be mapped to the case class you most expect to use:

   ```
   object Bars extends Table[Bar]("bar") {
     def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
     def name = column[String]("name")
     def * = id ~ name <>(Bar, Bar.unapply _)
   }
   ```

   Or you can even have it per-query:

   ```
   case class Baz(name: String, num: Int)

   // SELECT b.name, 1 FROM bars b WHERE b.id = 42;
   val q1 = 
      for (b <- Bars if b.id === 42) 
        yield (b.name ~ 1 <> (Baz, Baz.unapply _))
   ```

   Here the type of `q1`  is a `Query` with a *mapped* projection to `Baz`.
    When invoked, it returns a `List` of `Baz` objects:

   ```
    val result: List[Baz] = q1.list
   ```
3. Finally, as an aside, the `.?` offers **Option Lifting** - the Scala way of
   dealing with values that may not be.

   ```
    (id ~ name)   // Projection2[Int, String] // this is just for illustration
    (id.? ~ name) // Projection2[Option[Int], String]
   ```

   Which, wrapping up, will work nicely with your original definition of `Bar`:

   ```
   case class Bar(id: Option[Int] = None, name: String)

   // SELECT b.id, b.name FROM bars b WHERE b.id = 42;
   val q0 = 
      for (b <- Bars if b.id === 42) 
        yield (b.id.? ~ b.name <> (Bar, Bar.unapply _))


   q0.list // returns a List[Bar]
   ```
4. In response to the comment on how Slick uses `for` comprehensions:

   Somehow, monads always manage to show up and demand to
   be part of the explanation...

   For comprehensions are not specific to collections only.
   They may be used on any kind of *Monad*, and collections are
   just one of the many kinds of monad types available in Scala.

   But as collections are familiar, they make a good starting 
   point for an explanation:

   ```
   val ns = 1 to 100 toList; // Lists for familiarity
   val result = 
     for { i <- ns if i*i % 2 == 0 } 
       yield (i*i)
   // result is a List[Int], List(4, 16, 36, ...)
   ```

   In Scala, a for comprehension is syntactic sugar for
   method (possibly nested) method calls: The above code
   is (more or less) equivalent to:

   ```
   ns.filter(i => i*i % 2 == 0).map(i => i*i)
   ```

   Basically, anything with `filter`, `map`, `flatMap`
   methods (in other words, a *Monad*) can be used in a 
   `for` comprehension in place of `ns`. A good example
   is the [Option monad](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html). Here's the previous example
   where the same `for` statement works on both the 
   `List` as well as `Option` monads:

   ```
   // (1)
   val result = 
     for { 
       i <- ns          // ns is a List monad
       i2 <- Some(i*i)  // Some(i*i) is Option
         if i2 % 2 == 0 // filter
     } yield i2

   // Slightly more contrived example:
   def evenSqr(n: Int) = { // return the square of a number 
     val sqr = n*n         // only when the square is even
     if (sqr % 2 == 0) Some (sqr)
     else None
   }

   // (2)
   result = 
     for { 
       i <- ns  
       i2 <- evenSqr(i) // i2 may/maynot be defined for i!
     } yield i2
   ```

   In the last example, the transformation would perhaps look
   like this:

   ```
   // 1st example
   val result = 
     ns.flatMap(i => Some(i*i)).filter(i2 => i2 %2 ==0)

   // Or for the 2nd example
   result = 
     ns.flatMap(i => evenSqr(i))
   ```

   In Slick, queries are monadic - they are just objects with
   the `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` methods. So the `for` comprehension
   (shown in the explanation of the `*` method) just translates to:

   ```
   val q = 
     Query(Bars).filter(b => b.id === 42).map(b => b.name ~ 1)
   // Type of q is Query[(String, Int)]

   val r: List[(String, Int)] = q.list // Actually run the query
   ```

   As you can see, `flatMap`, `map` and `filter` are used to 
   generate a `Query` by the repeated transformation of `Query(Bars)`
   with each invocation of `filter` and `map`. In the case of 
   collections these methods actually iterate and filter the collection
   but in Slick they are used to generate SQL. More details here:
   [How does Scala Slick translate Scala code into JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758445/how-does-scala-slick-translate-scala-code-into-jdbc/13758728#13758728)

Comment: In '1' explanation block: It is not obvious that 'val q = ' is WrappingQuery, it looks like a List<Projection2> while reading the code. How is it possible the it transforms to Query..? (I'm still playing with your explanations to understand how it works. Thank you for this!)

Comment: @ses - added a (slightly long) explanation about this... Also, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454347/monads-with-java-8/13455602#13455602 - I realized that it's the almost same content.

Comment: Note to those experiencing mysterious compile errors, use foo.? for Option[T] columns or you'll get a difficult to read type mismatch. Thanks, Faiz!

Comment: This is a great answer... it would be great though if it could be updated for Slick 3.0

Answer (score 6):

Since no one else has answered, this might help to get you started. I don't know Slick very well.

From the [Slick documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/0.11.2/lifted-embedding.html):

> **Lifted Embedding:**
>
> Every table requires a * method contatining a default projection. This
> describes what you get back when you return rows (in the form of a
> table object) from a query. Slick’s * projection does not have to
> match the one in the database. You can add new columns (e.g. with
> computed values) or omit some columns as you like. The non-lifted type
> corresponding to the * projection is given as a type parameter to
> Table. For simple, non-mapped tables, this will be a single column
> type or a tuple of column types.

In other words, slick needs to know how to deal with a row returned from the database. The method you defined uses their parser combinator functions to combine your column definitions into something that can be used on a row.

Comment: ook. and Projection is just a representation of columns.. like:

final class Projection2[T1,T2](
  override val _1: Column[T1],
  override val _2: Column[T2]
)
extends Tuple2(_1,_2) with Projection[(T1,T2)] { ..

Comment: Now.. how come that: Bar has 'unapply' method ?

Comment: Aha.. - all case classes implement the Product trait, and unapply is Product's method. Magic.