# In Table for slick configuration where are only one value tuple doesn't work

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.5

When I have 2 or more parameters - it works, but **when 1** - it not compiles.
Tuple is for 2 or more parameters functions, I know.
But if I wan't the table with only one value?

```
case class Some(name: String)

class SomeTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Some](tag, "Some") {
  def name = column[String]("SomeNAME", O.PrimaryKey)

  override def * = name <>(Some.tupled, Some.unapply)
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244478/scala-projections-in-slick-for-only-one-column) out

Comment: I am not familiar with slick but this at least compiles: `override def * = name <> (Some.apply, Some.unapply)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can replace override by

```
override def * = name <>(Some.apply, Some.unapply)
```

It works for me.