# Converting scala.slick.lifted.Query to a case class

Tags: scala, slick

I have a slick table "UserSchema" as follows:

```
class UserSchema(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {

  def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)
  def password = column[String]("password", O.NotNull)
  def graduatingYear = column[Int]("graduating_year", O.NotNull)
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.NotNull, O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def * = (name, password, graduatingYear, id.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)

}
```

My "User" case class is as follows:

```
case class User(name: String, password: String, graduatingYear: Int, id: Option[Int] = None)
```

I have a `TableQuery[UserSchema]` in a `users` object, and a database in a `db` object.

How can I convert the following into a User object?

```
db withSession { implicit session =>
  users.filter(_.id === 1)
}
```

At the moment, I have

```
db withSession { implicit session =>
    val list = users.filter(_.id === id).list
    list(0)
}
```

which works, but seems ugly to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `list()` method returns a `List[User]` but if you are only interested in the first entry use `firstOption`:

```
db withSession { implicit session =>
  val users = TableQuery[UserSchema]
  val someUser: Option[User] = users.filter(_.id === id).firstOption
}
```

Which returns `Some(User)` if the query found something, else `None`, this is also more safe as it could happen that the query has no result and calling `list(0)` could result in an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map on the Slick query like this:

```
db withSession { implicit session =>
  val userlist = users.filter(_.id === id).list
    .map(user => User(user._1, user._2, user._3, Some(user._4)))
}
```

where `userlist` is a collection of `User`.

Comment: You don't need to map since the conversion to the case class is automatically executed by slick once you provide the [projection function (*)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906684/scala-slick-method-i-can-not-understand-so-far).

Comment: Thanks Ende! Didn't know that was possible. Found this link (http://blog.lunatech.com/2013/11/21/slick-case-classes) that also helps explain it.

Comment: You're welcome but note that this tutorial is for Slick 1.X, this syntax `id.? ~ name` is not used in version 2, also the answer I linked is old but it's very coincise and one of the best explaination around.