# Slick projection - making sense of type errors

Tags: scala, slick

I have the following code below, attempting to set up a relatively straightforward table mapping with companion class.

```
case class Client(
      id: Integer,
      givenName: String,
      familyName: String,
      birthDate: Option[Date],
      nationality: Option[String]
)

class ClientsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Client](tag, "Client") {

  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def givenName = column[String]("GIVEN_NAME", O.NotNull)
  def familyName = column[String]("FAMILY_NAME", O.NotNull)
  def birthDate = column[Date]("BIRTH_DATE", O.Nullable)
  def nationality = column[String]("NATIONALITY", O.Nullable)

  def * = (id, givenName, familyName, birthDate.?, nationality.?) <> ((Client.apply _).tupled, Client.unapply) 
}
```

The error I'm seeing is on the `<>` operator.

```
No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given types. 
Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List). 
Required level: scala.slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel Source type: (scala.slick.lifted.Column[Int], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String], scala.slick.lifted.Column[String], scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[java.sql.Date]], scala.slick.lifted.Column[Option[String]]) Unpacked type: (Integer, String, String, Option[java.sql.Date], Option[String]) Packed type: Any
```

Now, there's a [popular answer that describes aspects of slick projections in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906684/scala-slick-method-i-can-not-understand-so-far) that I've read backwards and forwards, and still I'm  missing something here.

I get that this projection function is attempting to create a default projection of the table for easy later query with the DSL.  And I get that what I'm trying to do here is transform a series of tuples (what really comes back from a database) into a series of `Client` objects.   I don't fully understand the magic of what's happening as of `<>` and everything after it, and so I'm a bit stuck on how to resolve this error.

Comment: There's a difference between `Int` and `Integer`. I think it might be the culprit.

Comment: Yes - that was it.  Is it idiomatic to use scala.Int instead of java.lang.Integer?

Comment: Definitely. I don't think I have seen `java.lang.Integer` outside of Java-compatible code snippets and libraries. Scala's `Int` all the way.